# How to make a big tridiagonal matrix with matrices?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, reshape, diagonal

How can I make a matrix H from two smaller matrices H_0 and H_1 as shown in the attached image? The final dimension is finite.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = np.ones(shape=(3,3))
a_r = a.reshape((-1,))
b_r = b.reshape((-1,))
b_r_ = np.diag(b_r,k=1)

b_r_ = b_r_ + b_r_.transpose()

for i in range(b_r_.shape[0]):
  
  if i < len(a_r):
    b_r_[i][i]=a_r[i]

  else:
    b_r_[i][i]=0
```

Output:

```
array([[1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 2., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 3., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 4., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 5., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 6., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

Concern:
I think this is not the most computationally efficient way but I think it works

Comment: This is not what I meant. H_0 and H_1 are matrices. Say H_0 is m x m matrix. First block  m x m block of H should be equal to H_0 . If H_1 is also m x m; the second horizontal block of H should b H_1 (from rows m+1 to 2m, columns 1 to m).

Comment: That sounds like stacking two matrices on top of each other. Did I get that right?

Answer (score 0):

```
H = np.kron(np.eye(r,dtype=int),H_0) + np.kron(np.diag(np.ones(r-1), 1),H_1) + np.kron(np.diag(np.ones(r-1), -1),transpose(conj(H_1))) #r = repetition
```